# Spring Boot + Mybatis @MapperScan and SqlSessionFactory

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mybatis

Im developing a new app using Spring Boot. I use Mybatis for persistance. Im using Java Config for everything I can.

I'm getting this exception when the app starts regarding creating my Mybatis mapper interface

```
exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'sqlSessionFactory' or 'sqlSessionTemplate' are required
```

My Sring Boot application class is set up like this

```
@SpringBootApplication
@MapperScan("com.mydomain.admin.service.dao")
public class AdminApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(AdminApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

The Mybatis mapper interface class is set up like this

```
package com.mydomain.admin.service.dao;
public interface AdminClientDAO {
@Select("SELECT clientId, name, enabledFlag as enabled, dateAdded, dateUpdated as updateDate FROM client")
public List<Client> findAll();
```

}

my datasource is configured with spring boot. I've named the properties
spring.datasource.* so spring boot with auto-configure the data source

Now, Im wondering if Im assuming too much spring boot magic. I assumed that spring boot would configure the sqlSessionFactory because mybatis was in the classpath..

Many examples I see show configuring the sqlSessionFactory as a @Bean in the Java Config.. Is this the way it should be done is should spring boot be doing some magic and auto-config  it?

Answer (score 1):

I found my issue. I was missing mybatis-spring-boot-starter

Answer (score 1):

I have

```
@Bean
public SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory() throws Exception {
    SqlSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
    return sessionFactory.getObject();
}
```

In class called Application.java which extends

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
```

And my Application.java is initialized in class which extends

```
org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer
```

And the datasource works fine in my Spring-Boot Application.
Hope this helps somebody searching for Spring Boot, Mybatis and SQLSessionFactory with datasource in spring.datasource.*